# Array is not coverting as string in SQLite

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I am trying to delete a value from SQLite and I am retrieving the value to be deleted from an array.

Here is the whole problem: when I use the value in delete statement it is showing in array format rather than String format.

Code:

```
deletestock="Delete from "+ st.tablename + " Where "+ st.column3 + " = '"+String.valueOf(populatestocks.a)+"'";
System.out.println(deletestock);
//Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().delete(st.tablename, st.column3 + "=" + abc, null);
Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(deletestock, null);
```

Array Decleration
    ArrayList a=new ArrayList();
above code populatestock.a is array

But logcat is some thing like this:

```
Delete from abc Where StockName = '[sdfd]'
```

but I need

```
Delete from abc Where StockName = 'sdfd'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: then it should be `String.valueOf(populatestocks.a[0])`

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am getting this error when I changed. `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to '
`

Comment: In addition to the arg formatting (where the correct answer is hard to figure out from the question - please provide more context), use `execSQL()` not `rawQuery()` for deletes.

Comment: Still the same issue my problem is when I retrive value from array I get as `[sdf]` but I need as `sdf`.. how can I achive this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with this:

```
deletestock="Delete from "+ st.tablename + " Where "+ st.column3 + " = '"+String.valueOf(populatestocks.a).subString(1, String.valueOf(populatestocks.a).length()-1)+"'";
```

That should return what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this didn't worked aswell :(

Comment: 03-11 15:10:39.733: E/AndroidRuntime(4851): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; regionStart=1; regionLength=-1
03-11 15:10:39.733: E/AndroidRuntime(4851):  at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
03-11 15:10:39.733: E/AndroidRuntime(4851):  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)

Comment: Before I was using the size of the array instead of the size of the string, now it could work

Comment: This worked... :) can you give me insight what is the whole logic is

Comment: I just used the string you were getting as result and I get a substring starting in the position 1 and finishing in the position `string.length()-1`. The function `subString(start,end)` returns a substring starting in the position start of the string and finishing in the position end-1. So I just get the substring from the position 1 of your array until the position length()-1 of you array. In the array [asds] the position 1 is `a` and the position length()-1 is `]`, but as well as  substring() gets the substring until end-1, it returns asds. Is that clear? If you have any question just ask

Comment: thats very clear.. thanks for your explanation. Just one more query... if I have two strings in array then what should be my logic?

Comment: I am sorry @Tony_craft.. I am unable to join in chat discussion... can you please add your comment here...There is a timezone issue so that it is not possible for me to join in chat

Comment: What do you mean with two strings in array? one array with two strings inside?

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the content of the first position in the `ArrayList` (if populatestocks.a is your ArrayList):

```
populatestocks.a.get(0)
```

in your code:

```
deletestock="Delete from "+ st.tablename + " Where "+ st.column3 + " = '" + populatestocks.a.get(0) + "'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am getting this error `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to `. This is my array decleration ` ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: you are using an `ArrayList` not an `Array`. I updated my post to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr `populatestocks.a` should be `populatestocks.a[0]`

Your question implies that you have an array of length 1, and you expect string concatenation to recognize this and treat it is a single value. It doesn't work like this, because even with only one element, it is still an array, not a value, and is treated as such.

Comment: @Siva Are you using a Collection, or an array? I think both would print the same. ArrayList<> is a collection, not an array. Use `populatestocks.a.get(0)`, if that is what you are using.

Comment: My array syntax is something like this: `ArrayList  a=new ArrayList ();`

Comment: Then again, that is not an array. Please do not call it an array; that means something else in Java. At any rate, if you only jave one value, do `populatestocks.a.get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an ArrayList, so you need to use get(index) instead of [].

Therefore your code should look like:

```
String.valueOf(populatestocks.a.get(0))
```

[See also javadoc on ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)